# Equivalent for objectmapper in python

Tags: java, python, apache-kafka

I want to serialize my data in python for sending data to Kafka as a producer. :-)

and also there is a client with java that will deserialize messages with java and `kafka.common.serialization`

**what is the equivalent for**

`objectmapper.writeValueAsString().getBytes()`

in python?

in other words, how should I serialize data with python to be readable from the consumer side(java)?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to get a `dict` object, then `json.dumps` it into the value of the Kafka record.

```
import json 
...

producer = KafkaProducer(...)

data = {"some":"data"}
producer.send(topic, value=json.dumps(data))
```